# C++ How to kill or "refresh" a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So let's say we have two functions, "waitForShortestTime" and "addTime".

```
void waitForShortestTime(tm time)
{
   sleep_until(system_clock::from_time_t (timelocal(&time)));
   cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

So this thread is waiting for a certain time to pass. This is the shortest time available among a series of times. But say on another thread, a user calls "addTime", which adds another time to the series. The time added may end up being even shorter than the time "thread B" is waiting for, so I want to kill that thread and "refresh it" so it checks for the shortest time again before waiting.

```
Schedule mySchedule;
thread t(&Schedule::lookForShortTime, mySchedule); //thread is set up.
//user input
mySchedule.addTime(time); //new time is added by user.
//kill thread
thread t(&Schedule::lookForShortTime, mySchedule); //new thread to consider new time.
```

But I'm wondering how I'd kill the current thread first.

Comment: You can't. There's no facility in the standard C++ thread library to "kill" an execution thread, in some way. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Just put shorter sleeps into a loop that tests a volatile variable against the current time, and update the volatile variable from the other thread.

Comment: Condition variables have a a `wait_until` method that takes a timeout parameter. That will do what you need. I still question your design, but they can be leveraged to make that design work.

Comment: @user207421 - volatile variables mix very poorly with threads because they play very poorly with CPU cache consistency between cores. Use `::std::atomic` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a condition variable? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable.

Instead of killing a thread, send a signal to it so that it wake up and then take appropriate action.

I highly recommmand you to buy and read the book **C++ Concurrency in Action** (https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition) as it give a lot of explanation on writing multithreaded code using standard C++.

So each time you need to add an event to process before any existing event, you could signal that thread to stop, wait for it to stop and start another thread.

Or you might also simply start another thread with a shorter timer for that new event combined with a maximum wait time that is a good compromise between the chance to have to add an event before and to have way too many wakeup is low.

For example, assume that most jobs are for next 30 minutes or more and you very rarely have a new job for the immediate next 5 minutes. You can then tell the thread to wait 5 minutes and when it wakeup, it check if any job should be scheduled before the end of next 5 minutes and if so, use a smaller wait duration.

Or if the required precision is not high (say you need to check within a minute or 2 of planned time), you can simply always wait at most that time (1 or 2 minutes) and check if you have something to do now.

In practice, also it is not necessary to kill the thread. You wake it up and let the thread check if there is something to do and if not what is the next time an item should be processed and use that for the wait time.

The event could also be used to quit the application.

Sometime, using a maximum delay can make the application more full proof by helping ensuring that if an event is somehow lost, data will be processed within a certain amount of time. Also, you can do some health check to see that for example you are not still processing previous job after a very long delay (for example, you have a bug that cause an infinite loop).

Comment: I didn't realize the condition variable has a timeout. The condition variable is the right answer.

Comment: Won't opening too many threads potentially cause problems in the long run though? How would I stop the new threads from getting out of control? I think join is one method, but that would stop the current thread and wouldn't allow the user to continue using the main function of the program, which isn't user friendly.

Comment: Well, your main thread does not have to wait much. You add the item to a queue and signal the processing thread. That thread will then take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need to do. It currently requires the fmt library, but that's easy to change. It uses a condition variable to do the magic:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

using timed_msg_t = ::std::pair<::std::chrono::system_clock::time_point,
                                 ::std::string>;

class time_smaller
{
 public:
   bool operator ()(timed_msg_t const &a, timed_msg_t const &b)
   {
      return b.first < a.first;
   }
};

using timer_queue = ::std::priority_queue<timed_msg_t,
                                          ::std::vector<timed_msg_t>,
                                          time_smaller>;

using ::std::mutex;
using ::std::condition_variable;
using ::std::thread;
using ::std::unique_lock;

static auto const start = ::std::chrono::system_clock::now();

void timer_queue_thread(mutex &queue_mutex,
                        condition_variable &queue_condition,
                        timer_queue &q)
{
   unique_lock<mutex> qlock(queue_mutex);
   while (!q.empty()) {
      auto now = ::std::chrono::system_clock::now();
      auto const &top = q.top();
      if (top.first <= now) {
         double milliseconds_from_start = (now - start) / ::std::chrono::milliseconds(1);
         ::fmt::print("At time: {}ms - \"{}\"\n", milliseconds_from_start, top.second);
         q.pop();
      } else {
         queue_condition.wait_until(qlock, top.first);
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   timer_queue tq;
   mutex queue_mutex;
   condition_variable queue_condition;
   {
      unique_lock<mutex> qlock(queue_mutex);
      tq.emplace(start + 60 * ::std::chrono::seconds(1), "Starting event.");
   }
   ::std::thread timer_processing{timer_queue_thread, ::std::ref(queue_mutex), ::std::ref(queue_condition), ::std::ref(tq)};
   while (true) {
      int seconds;
      ::std::string msg;
      ::std::cout << "Enter a time and message:\n";
      ::std::cin >> seconds;
      getline(::std::cin, msg);
      {
         unique_lock<mutex> qlock(queue_mutex);
         auto const qtime = ::std::chrono::system_clock::now() + seconds * ::std::chrono::seconds(1);
         tq.emplace(qtime, msg);
         queue_condition.notify_one();
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```